# In case of one to one mapping in Java springboot with JPA, I am getting null value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-one

I have two entities like below:

```
users:
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long userId;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private Address address;
}

Address:
public class Address {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long addressId;
    private String streetName;
    private Long userId;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName="userId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

I am doing userRepository.save(user); with user object as follows:

```
{
    "userName" : "test",
    "Address" : {
         "streetName" : "street"
    }
}
```

but in Address table, userId is coming as NULL even though there is a forign key relationship is there and when i am getting user entity Address is coming as NULL Can anyone please let me know where i am doing the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I changed the above code like this:

```
User.java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "addressId")
private Address address;

Address.java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private User user;
```

It worked fine.